# Unable to interface the contract while running test.js and how to get the abi while compiling using solc?

Tags: web3js, abi, solidity-0.5.x, solcjs

**Solidity Contract: index.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Inbox{
    string public message;

constructor(string memory IntialMessage) public{
    message = IntialMessage;
}

function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public{
    message = newMessage;
}
}
```

**compile.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname,"contracts","index.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,"utf8");

var input = {
language: 'Solidity',
sources: {
    'index.sol': {
        content: source
    }
},
settings: {
    outputSelection: {
        '*': {
            '*': [ '*' ]
        }
    }
}
}

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
output=JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

if(output.errors) {
output.errors.forEach(err => {
    console.log(err.formattedMessage);
});
} else {
const contracts = output.contracts["index.sol"];
console.log("Bytecode Of the Contracts:\n");
for (let contractName in contracts) {
    const contract = contracts[contractName];
    module.exports= 
          {"abi":contract.abi,"bytecode":contract.evm.bytecode.object};
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(buildPath, `${contractName}.json`), 
    JSON.stringify(contract.abi, null, 2), 'utf8');
    console.log(contractName+": "+contract.evm.bytecode.object+"\n");
}
}
```

**index.test.js:**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');  //Web3 is a constructor of the web3 module

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider()); //web3 is an instance of the web3 module
const {abi, bytecode} = require('../compile');
const inboxBuild = require('../build/Inbox.json');
const abiObj = require('solc/abi');

let newABI;
newABI = abiObj.update('0.3.6',inboxBuild);

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(newABI)
        .deploy({data:bytecode,arguments:["Hi there!"]})
        .send({from:accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
});

describe("Inbox",() => {
    it("deploys a contract", () => {
        console.log(inbox);
    });
});
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
Inbox
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.




npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! inbox@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the inbox@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aashutosh Singh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-24T04_11_07_715Z-debug.log
```

Thank you to whoever tries to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real problem with your code. Just take a look at the error message. It tells you that you only have 2 seconds time to execute your code. Cause of the nature of blockchain (and ethereum) your deploy will most likely take longer than this.

**So how do you fix it?**

In you project root folder you have a file called package.json. When running tests you most likely added a "test script" there.

So change from this:
`"scripts": { "test": "mocha"}`

To this:
"scripts": { "test": "mocha --timeout 40000" }

This way you now have 40 seconds to run your program. Now you need to execute your test.js like this. (I hope you already did it that way)

`npm run test`

**Where is my abi?**

Your index.test.js seems to get the abi in this line:

`const {abi, bytecode} = require('../compile');`

Now your `abi` is in the `abi variable`.